# Can't use declared function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, ring

how's it going?

My code can be found **[HERE](https://github.com/mmdsza/calc-api-learn)**

I've been trying to learn Clojure by following a [guide](https://github.com/anan44/it-starts-with-clojure), but I'm not quite sure why this piece of code isn't working.

Here's the code:

```
(ns calc-api.server.server
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.middleware.params :as params]
            [ring.util.http-response :as response]
            [reitit.ring.middleware.muuntaja :as muuntaja]
            [muuntaja.core :as m]
            [reitit.ring.coercion :as coercion]
            [reitit.ring :as ring]))


(def hello-routes
  ["/hello" {:get {:handler (fn [_]
                              (response/ok {:mesage "Hello Reitit!"}))}}])



(def app
  (ring/ring-handler
   (ring/router
    [hello-routes]
    {:data {:muuntaja m/instance
            :middleware [params/wrap-params
                         muuntaja/format-middleware
                         coercion/coerce-exceptions-middleware
                         coercion/coerce-request-middleware
                         coercion/coerce-response-middleware]}})
   (ring/create-default-handler)))




(defonce running-server (atom nil))

(defn start
  []
  (when (nil? @running-server)
    (reset! running-server (jetty/run-jetty #'app {:port  3000
                                                   :join? false})))
  (println "Server running in port 3000"))

(defn stop
  []
  (when-not (nil? @running-server)
    (.stop @running-server)
    (reset! running-server nil))
  (println "Server stopped"))
```

When I run the REPL and swap over to the calc-api namespace and run the (start) function:

```
lein repl
(in-ns 'calc-api.server.server)
(start)
```

I was expecting the server to run and print the "server is running on port x", but here's the outcome:

```
Syntax error compiling at (/tmp/form-init2855747266943058886.clj:1:1).
Unable to resolve symbol: start in this context
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? All help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT[1]**

Following [Alan Thompson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1822379/alan-thompson) suggestion, here's what happened:

Copied my code and dependencies to the template's folder, running lein clean + lein run results in

```
{:clojure.main/message
 "Syntax error compiling at (demo/core.clj:50:3).\nNo such namespace: log\n",
 :clojure.main/triage
 {:clojure.error/phase :compile-syntax-check,
  :clojure.error/line 50,
  :clojure.error/column 3,
  :clojure.error/source "core.clj",
  :clojure.error/path "demo/core.clj",
  :clojure.error/class java.lang.RuntimeException,
  :clojure.error/cause "No such namespace: log"},
 :clojure.main/trace
 {:via
  [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException,
    :message "Syntax error compiling at (demo/core.clj:50:3).",
    :data
    {:clojure.error/phase :compile-syntax-check,
     :clojure.error/line 50,
     :clojure.error/column 3,
     :clojure.error/source "demo/core.clj"},
    :at [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6812]}
   {:type java.lang.RuntimeException,
    :message "No such namespace: log",
    :at [clojure.lang.Util runtimeException "Util.java" 221]}],
  :trace
  [[clojure.lang.Util runtimeException "Util.java" 221]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler resolveIn "Compiler.java" 7388]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler resolve "Compiler.java" 7362]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSymbol "Compiler.java" 7323]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6772]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6749]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr parse "Compiler.java" 3824]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7113]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6793]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6749]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser parse "Compiler.java" 6122]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod parse "Compiler.java" 5471]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr parse "Compiler.java" 4033]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7109]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6793]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7099]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6793]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler access$300 "Compiler.java" 38]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser parse "Compiler.java" 596]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7111]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6793]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 6749]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7185]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7640]
   [clojure.lang.RT loadResourceScript "RT.java" 381]
   [clojure.lang.RT loadResourceScript "RT.java" 372]
   [clojure.lang.RT load "RT.java" 459]
   [clojure.lang.RT load "RT.java" 424]
   [clojure.core$load$fn__6856 invoke "core.clj" 6115]
   [clojure.core$load invokeStatic "core.clj" 6114]
   [clojure.core$load doInvoke "core.clj" 6098]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 408]
   [clojure.core$load_one invokeStatic "core.clj" 5897]
   [clojure.core$load_one invoke "core.clj" 5892]
   [clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6796 invoke "core.clj" 5937]
   [clojure.core$load_lib invokeStatic "core.clj" 5936]
   [clojure.core$load_lib doInvoke "core.clj" 5917]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 142]
   [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
   [clojure.core$load_libs invokeStatic "core.clj" 5974]
   [clojure.core$load_libs doInvoke "core.clj" 5958]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 137]
   [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
   [clojure.core$require invokeStatic "core.clj" 5996]
   [clojure.core$require doInvoke "core.clj" 5996]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 408]
   [user$eval142$fn__146 invoke "form-init13165779102252361276.clj" 1]
   [user$eval142 invokeStatic "form-init13165779102252361276.clj" 1]
   [user$eval142 invoke "form-init13165779102252361276.clj" 1]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7181]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7171]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7640]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler loadFile "Compiler.java" 7578]
   [clojure.main$load_script invokeStatic "main.clj" 475]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invoke "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$initialize invokeStatic "main.clj" 508]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 542]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invoke "main.clj" 539]
   [clojure.main$main invokeStatic "main.clj" 664]
   [clojure.main$main doInvoke "main.clj" 616]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 137]
   [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 705]
   [clojure.main main "main.java" 40]],
  :cause "No such namespace: log",
  :phase :compile-syntax-check}}
```

Which I don't think has to do anything with my original code?

**EDIT[2]**

I've found a solution which I don't like but works for my learning purposes. I changed the core.clj file to require the server namespace and call the start function from there.

```
(ns calc-api.core
  (:gen-class))
(require '[calc-api.server.server :as calc-api-server])
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (calc-api-server/start))
```

Which means I have to cmd+d every time I want to stop the server, but at least it works. Thanks for all the help provided.

Comment: What file is the code in?  Beware that hyphens in the NS must be underscores in the file name, e.g. `src/calc_api/server/server.clj` or similar

Comment: There's a main folder with doc, resources, server(which the server.clj is located in), src/calc_api(which core.clj is in), target, test.

So there are no undescores or hyphens in my server folder/file.

Comment: For a Leiningen project, source files (`*.clj`, `*.cljs` and `*.cljc`) are [typically under the `src` or `test` directories](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#directory-layout). I see that source file `server/server.clj` in your project should be at `src/calc_api/server/server.clj` instead.

Comment: @SteffanWestcott moved the folder over to src/calc_api/server/server.clj and the problem persists.

Comment: @MauricioSouza Great, but please update the code in your Github repo, otherwise we will struggle to help you effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is difficult to diagnose with only the repl information & error. As an expedient, I would suggest starting with [a known working template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Do a `git clone` as the README describes, then `lein clean; lein test` to verify the install (& your java, etc) are configured correctly.

At that point, copy your code into `src/clj/demo/core.clj` and then try `lein clean; lein run`.  Even if it doesn't work, you will get a much more detailed error message, including usable line numbers for any error.

**Please update your question** with the results of this experiment.